# How can I improve this `if`-statement?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, refactoring

How can I improve this `if`-statement in ruby?

Original `if`-statement:

```
status = 'None available', css_class = 'grey'
if pending_final > 0
  status = 'Pending'
  css_class = 'red'
elsif requested_final == 0 && request.granted
  status = 'Granted'
  css_class = 'green'
elsif requested_final == 0 && request.granted == false
  status = 'Not requested'
  css_class = 'red'
end
```

I was trying to refactor like this:

```
status, css_class = if pending_final > 0
 'Pending', 'red'
elsif requested_final == 0 && request.granted
 'Granted', 'green'
 # and so on...
else
 'None available', 'grey'
end
```

But then I have a syntax error in the "," commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
status, css_class = if pending_final > 0
 ['Pending', 'red']
elsif requested_final == 0 && request.granted
 ['Granted', 'green']
 # and so on...
else
 ['None available', 'grey']
end
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful! I was missing the "["